# A question about the proof of Bernstein-Type Lemmas

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, normed-spaces

In the book *Bahouri, Hajer, Jean-Yves Chemin, and Raphaël Danchin. Fourier analysis and nonlinear partial differential equations. Vol. 343. Springer Science & Business Media, 2011.*,
In the proof of Lemma 2.1. there are the following inequalities
$$
\begin{split}
\left \| \partial^\alpha g  \right \|_{L^r} &\leq \left \| \partial^\alpha g  \right \|_{L^\infty} + \left \| \partial^\alpha g  \right \|_{L^1} \quad \color{Red}{\mathbf{(1)}}\\
&\leq C\left \| (1 + |\cdot|^2)^d \partial^\alpha g  \right \|_{L^\infty} \quad \color{Red}{\mathbf{(2)}}\\
&\leq C\left \| (\mathrm{Id} + \Delta)^d ((\cdot)^\alpha \phi)  \right \|_{L^1} \quad \color{Red}{\mathbf{(3)}}\\
&\leq C^{k+1} \quad \color{Red}{\mathbf{(4)}}
\end{split}
$$
where,

$g = \mathcal{F}^{-1} \phi$,

$\phi$ is a function of $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ with value $1$ near $B = \{ξ ∈ \mathbb{R}^d : |ξ| ≤ R\}$ with $R > 0$,

$\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is the space of smooth compactly supported functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$,

$C$ is a constant,

$1/r = 1-1/p+1/q$ with $p,q \in [1, \infty]$.

My questions are:

for $\color{Red}{\mathbf{(1)}}$, is it also true for the inequality $\left \| \partial^\alpha g  \right \|_{L^r} \leq \left \| \partial^\alpha g  \right \|_{L^1}$?

I can understand from $\color{Red}{\mathbf{(1)}}$ to $\color{Red}{\mathbf{(2)}}$. But I'm not clear from $\color{Red}{\mathbf{(2)}}$ to $\color{Red}{\mathbf{(3)}}$.

Why is it the same constant $C$ from $\color{Red}{\mathbf{(3)}}$ to $\color{Red}{\mathbf{(4)}}$?

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck at this too so here is my attempt, (I am sure there must be a cleaner way):
\begin{align}
\lVert \partial^\alpha \phi \rVert_{L^r} &\leq \lVert \partial^\alpha \phi \rVert_{L^1}^\theta \lVert \partial^\alpha \phi \rVert_{L^\infty}^{1 - \theta} \leq (\lVert \partial^\alpha \phi \rVert_{L^1} + \lVert \partial^\alpha \phi \rVert_{L^\infty})^\theta (\lVert \partial^\alpha \phi \rVert_{L^1} + \lVert \partial^\alpha \phi \rVert_{L^\infty})^{1 - \theta} \\
&= \lVert \partial^\alpha \phi \rVert_{L^1} + \lVert \partial^\alpha \phi \rVert_{L^\infty}  \leq C_d \lVert \langle x \rangle^{2d} \partial^\alpha \phi \rVert_{L^\infty} + \lVert \partial^\alpha \phi \rVert_{L^\infty}  \leq 2C_d \lVert \langle x \rangle^{2d}\partial^\alpha \phi \rVert_{L^\infty} \\
&= C_d \lVert (I - \Delta)^d (\xi ^a \hat{\phi}) \rVert_{L^1}  \leq C_{\phi,d} \lVert (I - \Delta)^d \xi ^\alpha \rVert_{L^1}  \leq C_{\phi,d} \lVert (I - \Delta)^d \xi ^a \rVert_{L^\infty(K)} \lvert K \rvert \\
&\leq C_{\phi,d} \lvert K \rvert \sum_{j \leq d} \Delta ^j \lvert \xi \rvert^{k} = C_{\phi, d} \lvert K \rvert \sum_{j \leq d} \Delta ^{j-1} (\partial_{rr} + \tfrac{d-1}{r} \partial_r) r^k \\
&= C_{\phi, d} \lvert K \rvert \sum_{j \leq d} k (k + d - 2) \Delta ^{j-1} r^{k - 2} \\
&= C_{\phi, d} \lvert K \rvert \sum_{0 \leq j \leq d} \prod_{0\leq i \leq j} (k - 2i)(k - 2i + d - 2) r^{k - j} \\
&\leq C_{\phi, d} \lvert K \rvert r^k \sum_{j \leq d} \prod_{i \leq j} ( k + 2d)( k + 3d + 2) \\
&\leq C_{\phi, d} \lvert K \rvert r^k \sum_{j \leq d} \prod_{i \leq j} (1 + d)^{2 + k}(1 + d)^{3 + k } \\
&\leq C_{\phi, d} \lvert K \rvert r^k (1 + d)^{5 + 2k} \sum_{j \leq d} \\
&\leq C_{\phi,d} ((\lvert K \rvert \lor 1) (1 + d)^5)^{k+1}  = ((1 + d)^5 (\lvert K \rvert \lor 1) C_{\phi, d})^{k+1}  = C_{\phi, d}^{k+1}
\end{align}
where $K = {\rm supp\,}\hat{\phi}$ and $ r \leq  \lvert K \rvert \lor 1$ as $ B$ is centered at $0$ and I have taken $\phi \in \mathcal{S} : \hat{\phi} \in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^d) $ and $\hat{\phi}|_{B} =1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Inequality 1**: short answer: Lebesgue interpolation and Young's inequality.

First observe by Holder's inequality that for $\frac1r = \frac1p + \frac1q$, we have $\|fg\|_{L^r} \le \|f\|_{L^p} \|g\|_{L^q}$.
Then for arbitrary $\theta\in(0,1),$ it is easy to verify
$$ \|f\|_{L^r} = \|f^\theta f^{1-\theta}\|_{L^r} \le \|f^\theta\|_{L^p} \|f^{1-\theta}\|_{L^q} =  \|f\|^\theta_{L^{\theta p}} \|f\|^{1-\theta}_{L^{(1-\theta)q}}. \tag{*}$$
Now, let $r\le p \le q $ be arbitrary and choose $\theta$ so that $\frac1r = \frac\theta p + \frac{(1-\theta)}q = \frac1{ p/\theta} + \frac{1}{q/(1-\theta)}$. Then from (*) it follows that
$$ \|f\|_{L^r} \le \|f\|^\theta_{L^{p}} \|f\|^{1-\theta}_{L^{q}}.$$
Now  apply [Young's inequality for products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products) $ab \le \frac{a^p}p + \frac{b^q}q$ to obtain
$$ \|f\|_{L^r} \le \|f\|_{L^{p}} + \|f\|_{L^{q}}.$$

(I would memorise the above inequalities as they are quite useful.)
And no, $\|f\|_{L^r} \le \|f\|_{L^1}$ is not true. Consider $f(x) = |x|^{-\alpha} \mathbf 1_{|x|<1}$  for an appropriate choice of $\alpha$.

**Inequality 2**: this is Sobolev embedding.

**Inequality 3**: This is the inequality for the Fourier transform $ \| \mathcal F u \|_{L^\infty} \le \| u \|_{L^1}.$ It's just triangle inequality for integrals since $|e^{i\theta}|=1$.

**Inequality 4**: We expand the brackets and get a huge sum. The constant $C$ can change from line to line, I will try to subscript the dependence. Triangle inequality gives
$$  \| (\operatorname{Id} + \Delta)^d ((\cdot)^\alpha \phi \|_{L^1} \le \int \sum_{\beta: |\beta|\le 2d} C_d|\partial^\beta (x^\alpha \phi(x))| dx \le  \sum_{\substack{\beta,\gamma \\ |\beta|\le 2d\\ 0\le \gamma \le \beta}} C_{d,\gamma,\beta} \int|\partial^{\beta-\gamma} x^\alpha| |\partial^\gamma \phi(x)| dx $$

Focus on a single summand: observe that $|\partial^{\beta-\gamma} x^\alpha| \le C_{\alpha,\beta-\gamma} |x|^{k-|\beta-\gamma|} \le C_{\alpha,d} |x|^{k}$. The above integrals are only over the support of $\phi$ so $|x|<C_0$ for some large enough $C_0$. Thus
$$\int|\partial^{\beta-\gamma} x^\alpha| |\partial^\gamma \phi(x)| dx \le  C_0^k \|\phi\|_{W^{|\gamma|,1}}.$$ Note that $\|\phi\|_{W^{|\gamma|,1}}$ and $\sum_{\substack{\beta,\gamma \\ |\beta|\le 2d\\ 0\le \gamma \le \beta}} C_{d,\gamma,\beta} $ are constants depending on $k$ and $d$. By allowing $C_0$ to be bigger if necessary we obtain the required inequality. (IIRC the constant should be something like $k! C^k$ but I think they ignore the $k!$...?)